# difference in using sklearn.utils.resample with stratify and without stratify

Tags: python, scikit-learn

What is difference in using sklearn.utils.resample with stratify and without stratify?

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.resample.html

```
import numpy
from sklearn.utils import resample


y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
res = resample(y, n_samples=5, replace=False, random_state=0)
print (res)
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

res = resample(y, n_samples=5, replace=False, stratify=y, random_state=0)
print (res)

[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Stratify` means the distribution in your original classes is preserved.

See the frequencies in original distribution:

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
seed=42
np.random.seed(seed)
y = np.random.choice([0,1],size=100000, p=[.5,.5])
np.unique(y,return_counts=True)
(array([0, 1]), array([49934, 50066]))
```

Then, the resample without `stratify`:

```
res = resample(y, n_samples=10000, replace=True, stratify=None, random_state=seed)
np.unique(res,return_counts=True)
(array([0, 1]), array([5049, 4951]))
```

And finally with stratification:

```
res = resample(y, n_samples=10000, replace=True, stratify=y,random_state=seed)
np.unique(res,return_counts=True)
(array([0, 1]), array([4993, 5007]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my real problem, the `Ys` are same class, but distributed with locations (I have two other columns longitude and latitude) . How can I re-sample with stratification so that the sampled results maintain the spatial distribution of original data?

Comment: Cut your data into stratas and resample accordingly.

Comment: `Cut your data into stratas`, could you elaborate it ?

Comment: I would advise you to ask a new question clearly stating what you want, providing as much data as you can.

Comment: sure i will do it soon, please answer me there as well.

Comment: I think there is a readily available solution for you [here](https://github.com/gboeing/2014-summer-travels/blob/master/clustering-scikitlearn.ipynb)

Answer (score 2):

The stratify option makes it so that the distribution of classes present in the full data will be kept in the sample. The fact that it didn't seem to matter in your example (as the same amount of 1s and 0s was getting returned) was simply a matter of coincidence. You can see that that is not always the case, by changing the random_state and noticing that the ratio of 1s to 0s doesn't always stay the same for non-stratified samples, whereas for the stratified ones it always follows that of your input data (4/5 are 1s):

```
In [1]: import numpy
   ...: from sklearn.utils import resample

In [2]: y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

In [3]: resample(y, n_samples=5, replace=False, random_state=10)
Out[3]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

In [4]: resample(y, n_samples=5, replace=False, stratify=y, random_state=10)
Out[4]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

In [5]: resample(y, n_samples=5, replace=False, random_state=42)
Out[5]: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

In [6]: resample(y, n_samples=5, replace=False, stratify=y, random_state=42)
Out[6]: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

In [7]: resample(y, n_samples=5, replace=False, random_state=0)
Out[7]: [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

In [8]: resample(y, n_samples=5, replace=False, stratify=y, random_state=0)
Out[8]: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my real problem, the `Ys` are same class, but distributed with locations (I have two other columns longitude and latitude) . How can I re-sample with stratification so that the sampled results maintain the spatial distribution of original data?

Comment: I believe you would have to find a way to consolidate the longitude and latitude columns into 1 single column representing the location (maybe clustering the locations somehow), and then you pass that column as the `stratify` param to the `resample` function.

Comment: yes, I was thinking about that, however, do not know how can I scalarize longitude and latitude columns into 1 single column

Answer (score 0):

stratification in general is an approach to maintain the original class proportion in resulting subsets.It is the technique to ensure training and test sets share approximately the same ratio of examples from each class, so that consistent predictive performance scores can be achieved in both the sets.

If the dataset has high class imbalance, in the worst-case scenario, the test set may not contain any instance of a minority class at all. Thus,
a recommended practice is to divide the dataset in a stratified fashion. Here, stratification simply means that we randomly split a dataset such that each class is correctly represented in the resulting subsets (the training and the test set) 
It shall be noted that random subsampling in non-stratified fashion is usually not a big concern when working with relatively large and balanced datasets.